# MySQLi issue with IIS7

Tags: php, mysqli

I need your help ... suddenly PHP stopped working at my IIS7 therefore i reinstalled it.

After reinstalling php there seems to be a problem with MySQLi.
Even if i try to open phpmyadmin but i am getting the following error.

```
The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. <a href="Documentation.html#faqmysql" target="documentation"><img src="themes/dot.gif" title="Documentation" alt="Documentation" class="icon ic_b_help" /></a>
```

I searched stackoverflow/google but couldn't find any solution.

Comment: What version of php are you using?

Comment: Did you uncomment this line in your php.ini file: `;extension=php_mysqli.dll`?

Comment: Do you have php_mysqli.dll in the extension folder? Also see your error log to see if there are issues when IIS started

Comment: i an using PHP 5.6.1 & i did uncomment the dll in ini file

Comment: php_mysqli.dll is in the extension folder.  how to check the iis error log